# Call the ajax function again after Complete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to re-execute the function with other parameter in the complete callback, but it isn't working as I want. It works well at the first call, but when I call it again, it only alerts the test alert twice and doesn't execute the function again. My intention is to execute the function with another parameter,that is the id of the element every time that the user click on the element. I appreciate if anyone could help me, what should I do? Thanks. =)

```
 jQuery(function($){  

    var load_pages = function($page){  
            $.ajax({  
                type       : "POST",  
                data       : {page_name : $page},  
                dataType   : "html",  
                url        : "http://localhost/includes/loadpages.php",
                beforeSend : function(){
                    $("#content").addClass("hide");

                    if($page.substr(0,9) == "categoria"){
                        $("#content").removeClass("hide");
                        $("#the-portfolio").remove();
                    }

                },
                success    : function(data){
                    $data = $(data);  
                    if($data.length){
                        if($page == 'lista_portfolio'){
                            $(".submenu").append($data);
                            $(".submenu").append('<div class="end"></div>');

                        }
                        else{
                            if(!$("#content") ==  false){
                                $("#wrapper").append('<div id="content"></div>');
                            }
                            $("#content").append($data);  
                            $(".foot").animate({bottom: 0},700,'easeOutExpo');
                            $data.fadeIn(500);

                        }   
                    } 
                },  

                error     : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {  
                    alert(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);  
                }, 

                complete : function() {
                    $("#portfolio_categories_list li a").click(function(){
    alert("test");
                        $categoria = $(this).attr("title").split("Ver todos os posts arquivados em ");
                        load_pages("categoria"+$categoria[1]);
                        return false;
                        });
                }
        });
        }// end load_pages
});
```

Comment: Try adding `cache: false;` as one of your AJAX params

Comment: Doesn't works, I have already tried...

Comment: Try re-executing it in the success function, not the complete function.

Comment: What's your network tab look like in the console? Is the request even being sent again?

Comment: Are you just trying to bind a click handler to a dynamically-added element? Use event delegation instead, so you just do it once. See the `.on()` method.

Comment: @tymeJV, it is not sending the request again, what should I do?

Comment: Sounds like the request is cached, when you add `cache: false,` is it doing anything different or just a whole lot of nothing?

Comment: nothing, the cache is setted to false

Comment: I found the solution, the problem was because of the return false inside the beforeSend function, I commented the lines where I was returning false in this function and it works fine, remembering that I put my request out of the complete function, thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to call `load_pages()` on complete because it causes a [Recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) which can make you run out of memory.

Instead, call your function out of the `$.ajax` and then by binding the event `click`, like this.

```
 $(document).on("click","#portfolio_categories_list li > a",function(e){

       e.preventDefault();

       alert("test");
       $categoria = $(this).attr("title").split("Ver todos os posts arquivados em ");
       load_pages("categoria"+$categoria[1]);

 });
```

Comment: It's not really recursion, because it's a callback. The original function has already returned.

Comment: It doesn't works, I have already tried it too, but I think because the element is loaded inside the function, it only can recognize it in the complete function. But I'm not sure, I thought this way would work too but don't... It had no changes, the function still loading the right content at the first time and doing not in the second time, alerting just one time this way... this alert was just to see if was in the complete function, because I tried to put this function in the sucess function too, but doesn`t works

Answer (score 0):

Did not see why you adding the event handler in complete callback, bind the event after you append the element to the dom in success callback should work well. And please provide some console/XHR requests output to help check your problem, put more console log instead of alert will help to track the problem